# Unable to start EAR in Liberty Server in debug mode

Tags: debugging, websphere-liberty, eclipse-oxygen

Liberty server is started and when adding EAR to the server it is not starting and the server is terminated.

Whereas finding no issues in starting the application in regular mode.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How exactly did you attempt to start the server in "debug mode" ?   Do you see any output on the console or any logs generated?

Comment: Facing the same Issue.. No error I can see in console. Debug is attempted via eclipse oxygen.

Comment: Without a recreate sample or some kind of error it's hard to suggest anything.   Is this a Maven or Gradle project?   If so maybe you could consider using Maven/Gradle to manage your Liberty install / deploy  rather than Eclipse, which is the approach our guides show:  https://openliberty.io/guides/

Comment: This is the Gradle project

Comment: For someone to help you might have to give some more detail about what commands you are issue with which tools, sample config, or even an entire source repo.    Let me mention we do have a Gradle guide:  https://openliberty.io/guides/gradle-intro.html   If you use the "dev mode" from the `libertyDev` task you will start the server in debug mode, and be able to attach a debugger.